# Обработка координат

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу запускать скрипт, когда мой объект в юнити, допустим, преодолеет 4.7f по координате  "y" в 2д пространстве. Как мне это сделать, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё одним решением, которое не потребует от вас в каждом кадре делать проверку расстояния может стать размещение [BoxCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html) с проставленным флажком [IsTrigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-isTrigger.html).

У [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) и его наследников есть метод *OnTriggerEnter2D*. Этот метод вызовется, если на объекте с этим скриптов висит какой-то *Collider2D* с галочкой *IsTrigger* и в этот коллайдер входит какой-то другой объект. Параметром в этот метод как раз и будет передан этот объект.

Другими словами - вы создаёте в определённой точке в вашей игре "тригер"(объект с коллайдером и скриптом, который будет что-то делать с игроком, который в этот коллайдер войдет), растягиваете границы колайдера, как вам нужно, а когда персонаж игрока попадает в эту зону - происходит действие (например, ускорение, телепортация в другую точку или вообще что угодно).

Таким образом вы можете делать что угодно без конкретного отслеживания положения игрока.

Answer (score 1):

И конструкторе объявите переменные

```
public Speed = 1f;
private Vector3 _endPos;
```

При старте установите _endPos

```
_endPos = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 4.7f, 0);
```

И в Update добавьте

```
 if (transform.position != _endPos)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _endPos, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Это пример простейшего способа плавно передвинуть объект к другой точке.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но хотелось бы рассмотреть случай, если я сам управляю объектом и мне надо постоянно проверять находиться ли мой объект выше этой координаты.

Comment: if (transform.position.y > _startPosY)
        {
            //ToDo
        } или смотрите насколько изменяется расстояние между двумя объектами